# Does Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 E-mail Router work with Exchange 2016?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, exchange-server-2016

We have on-prem Dynamics CRM 2011 and Exchange 2010. We're migrating to Exchange 2016 but need to make sure that our existing CRM 2011 is not affected.

Can anyone confirm compatibility of CRM 2011 E-mail Router with Exchange 2016?

Answer (score 1):

Official Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 is not supported with Exchange 2016 according to the [Compatibility with Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3005163/compatibility-with-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011). So I would upgrade that as well to ensure its up to date and if you run into any issues where you need the help from Microsoft you could get some help here.

Comment: We're in the process of upgrading our CRM 2011 organisation to 2016, but this is an ongoing project that won't be ready by the time our Exchange 2016 project is ready. We'll need to upgrade Exchange before CRM and I need to test unofficial compatibility.

Comment: The correct way to perform that is a coexistence scenario with exchange 2010 and 2016. then you still can point the old crm to the old server while you run ms exchange 2016. or upgrade the crm at first to a higher version so that it supports ms exchange 2016 as well as 2010.